Opening protected Excel File with GetObject()
I want to use the GetObject() method to open a protected Excel file in write protected mode and to suppress the protection dialogue:
Dim sh as Worksheets

Set sh = GetObject("C:\MyData.xlsx").Worksheets("MySheet")

The method is elegant as it doesn't display the file. I only want to read some data from it and close it after that.
Is it possible to open the file without the writing protection dialogue?
I tried different methods as Workbook.Open but the GetObject method seems to be the best way for my problem. I know that Workbook.Open has a parameter to suppress the protection dialogue. My question is, whether it is possible with the GetObject method?

How did you conclude that "the GetObject method seems to be the best way"? What exactly is your problem? Could you share the complete code, the one that uses Workbooks.Open() and would accomplish what you need? Add the information to your post (not in the comments).

Are the workbook having the code and "C:\MyData.xlsx" in different Excel sessions? What does "it doesn't display the file" mean? What kind of protection are you talking about? Do you mean password protected? Didn't you already try it?

Do you really mean to suppress the password? If so, this is not possible. I mean to open the workbook without knowing the password. But if you already opened it (of course, writing the password, manually or in code) you can do what you show, even if the workbook it is open in a different session. But this does not mean anything, I am afraid...

Is what you're trying to is open a password protected file and then read from it?  If so, then Excel isn't going to allow you to do this since it's the kind of thing that password protection is meant to avoid.

I want to open an Excel file that has a write protection password in read only mode like it  is possible with Workbook.open(sFilename, , True). That is already a possible solution. I simply wanted to know wheter it is possible to use the GetObject function instead.

You cannot bypass protection. You can refer only such an open workbook, but its opening has been produced supplying the password. The same with Set sh = Workbooks("C:\MyData.xlsx").Worksheets("MySheet"). If the workbook is open in the same Excel session.
